# Wait for external api method to finish

Tags: c#, api, asynchronous, async-await

I have a api-dll in which a method executes a long running job. During this execution, I have the possibility to get the current state of the job which is "Started" while the job is running and "Finished" if the job has ended. I have no other way to detect whether the external job is running or finished.

Now I call this api method from my own dll and I could write a "while"

```
var jobState = SomeApi.GetJobState();
while (jobState.JobStatus == EnumJobStatus.STARTED)
{
   Thread.Sleep(2000);
   jobState = SomeApi.GetJobState();
}
```

The Problem here is clearly that this will use quite much cpu which is a no-go.

So I need to find another way to wait for the job to finish. does anybody have a suggestion?

Any help is highly appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of a while loop you could make another thread that would check the state in a specific intervall (i.e. all 5 minutes).

Comment: Your code that calls this api-dll - does it stay in a running state or does it do something and stop?  Meaning, something needs to stay running to check on SomeApi.GetJobState() (maybe a thread that you control).  Or, another angle, does SomeApi provide a job ID that you can load dynamically to call SomeApi.GetJobState()?

Comment: Hi Leon

Thanks for the input but I need to avoid that the caller continues with further processing until the API has finished its job

Comment: Hi Toni

The whole thing should behave like a sync call. So the caller (me) should only continue after the api-dll has finished its job

Answer (score 4):

You could use Observables for that:

```
SomeApi.JobStart();
var jobStatus = await Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
      .Select(_ => SomeApi.GetJobState())
      .Where(x => x != EnumJobStatus.STARTED)
          .FirstAsync();

// or instead of .FirstAsync()

          .Where(..)
          .Take(1)
          .Subscribe(()=> /* do something */); // you can dispose subscription to cancel the timer
```

`jobStatus` will contain the first not `STARTED` code.

`Observable.Interval` uses schedulers, so it's very light on CPU. You can also very easily add cancelation of waiting via `TakeUntil`.

Comment: Hi Krzysztof

You're a god *thumbsup* :-) I forgot about the observable...thank you very much, will check and give feedback :-)

Comment: Also remember that you can pass `IScheduler` to `Interval`, so that if you can mock `SomeApi`, the test don't have to run in real time, they can be instant with `TestScheduler`

Comment: Hi Krzysztof :)

Actually I had to wait with testing. In general it works, but the issueI have now is, that called from a test project above  code does not return. It should return "FINISHED" but the test project is still running even if the job has finished. Any idea? :)

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is `async-await`, try this:

```
async Task WaitForJobToCompleteAsync()
{
    while (SomeApi.GetJobState().JobStatus == EnumJobStatus.STARTED)
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }
}
```